# How can i extend my system drive?

Tags: ssd, raid, dynamic-disk

I have Windows 7 installed on a basic volume on my 128GB SSD. I have now bought a 256GB SSD and want to add this space to my original 128GB SSD.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your two drives will never be on the same partition. However, there are a few things you can do.

1. Usually, the motherboards come with two SATA slots for hard drives. If you are using a desktop PC, you could add the second HDD inside the main CPU case and hook it up via the regular SATA cable.
2. If you have the original installation DVD for your Windows 7, I would personally recommend that you should format the new hard drive and make that your primary partition, and then add the older HDD as your secondary.
3. If you have a laptop, however, you may not have the space to do #1 above. Try #2, and then attach the other hard drive using an external HDD case via USB.

Answer (score 0):

IF your PC has "fake raid" baked into the motherboard, you may be able to reinstall the system in a RAID 0 configuration, but generally speaking I believe @SudiptaChatterjee is correct.  I believe Windows 7 does have software RAID built in to it, but you can't use it on the boot drive (unlike Linux)